# How to enable a button in another class involving ActionListener

Tags: java, user-interface, button

I have this code that I am referencing in Java Eclipse:

```
public class ClassWithButton extends JFrame{
    private final JPanel Your_Panel_name;

    public void enableButtons() {
    for (Component c : Your_Panel_name.getComponents()) {
      if (c instanceof JButton) 
         c.setEnabled(true);
     }
  }
}
```

Then there is a class which implements `ActionListener.java`

```
public class ActionListenerImpl implements ActionListener{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){

    }
}
```

I have a button in a class that extends JFrame and I have a panel in which I disabled two buttons on it. I have another class that extends ActionListener, when I press another button on the panel, I  want the 2 disabled buttons to be enabled, how would I go about doing so?

Comment: Create a reference to the class with `enableButtons()` in your class with the `ActionListener`.

Comment: How would I create a reference class? Sorry, new to Java :/

Comment: You have a class we'll call `ButtonClass` that has a method `enableButtons()`. Lets say you also have a class called `ActionClass` that extends `ActionListener`. You would need to define an object `ButtonClass b` within `ActionClass`, then in your `actionPerformed`, you could call `b.enableButtons();`. Don't forget to instantiate `b`, or you'll get a `NullPointerException`.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you define your own `Listener` class to achieve your goal.

First, define a `Listener` class.

```
public interface ButtonEnabledListener {
    void buttonEnabled(boolean isEnabled);
}
```

Second, implement this `Listener` for your `JFrame` or `JPanel` class.

```
public YourJPanel extends JPanel implements ButtonEnabledListener {
    void buttonEnabled(boolean isEnabled) {
        for (JButton button : buttons) {
            button.setEnabled(isEnabled);
        }
    }
}
```

Last, in another class, pass in your frame or panel and fire the event. Since your class implements ActionListener, so fire the event in the implemented method.

```
public AnotherClass implements ActionListener {
    JButton yourButton;
    ButtonEnabledListener listener;
    public AnotherClass(ButtonEnabledListener yourPanel) {
       yourButton = new JButton("enable buttons in my panel");
       yourButton.addActionListener(this);
       listener = yourPanel;
    }
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        listener.buttonEnabled(true);                    
    }
}
```

Comment: For my JPanel class, it extends JPanel, I am able to extend and implement?

Comment: @CenaMaine Yes, you could only subclass a single class, but you can implement multiple interfaces at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

With the code you've given, here's a quick example of how the reference works, but this is not the way I would implement it.

```
public class ClassWithButton extends JFrame{
    private final JPanel Your_Panel_name;
    ActionListenerImpl act;
    JButton otherButton;
    public ClassWithButton()
    {
        act = new ActionListenerImpl(this);
        otherButton = new JButton("Click to enable");
        otherButton.addActionListener(act);
    }
    public void enableButtons() {
        for (Component c : Your_Panel_name.getComponents()) {
            if (c instanceof JButton) 
                c.setEnabled(true);
        }
    }
}

public class ActionListenerImpl implements ActionListener{
    ClassWithButton b;
    public ActionListenerImpl(ClassWithButton b)
    {
        this.b = b;
    }
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
        b.enableButtons();
    }
}
```

Comment: Okay, makes sense, but where does "this" come from?

Comment: @CenaMaine Good question! `this` comes from the reference to `ClassWithButton`. So when I say `act = new ActionListenerImpl(this);`, I want the `this` to reference the current object that is being invoked. And that object is of type `ClassWithButton`. So when I use it in the ActionListenerImpl, the type for the constructor's parameter will be of type `ClassWithButton`.

Comment: Thank you for your help!